# Is it a good idea to use custom class without generics instead of ordinary collection in Java?

Tags: java

For example, I have a Java class for shop order:

```
public class Order {
    private List<Item> items;
    // some other fields here
}
```

Then I created my own class `Items extends ArrayList<Item>` and applied it in Order class:

```
public class Order {
    private Items items;
    // some other fields here
}
```

Is it a good idea? What are the advantages and disadvantages of this approach?

Comment: Do you have a reason **for** doing that?

Comment: Is there anything an `Items` can do that an `ArrayList<Item>` can't?  If not, why do you want it?

Comment: @ernest_k This is not my approach, to be honest. The author suggested using such a replacement if a collection is used frequently. No additional functionality is expected from the custom class.

Comment: @Abra this question is a poor fit over there, see [What is the problem with "Pros and Cons"?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260). Recommended reading: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on the domain you are modeling.

Is the list of items, separate from the order, an own concept with special meaning in your domain or is it just a technical detail to implement an aggregation or composition?
Does `Items` have operations a usual list does not have or does `ArrayList<Item>` have any operations you want `Items` not to have?
Do you regularly use that list in other methods (apart from iterating over all entries) and pass it around?

If the answers are mostly yes (and I think the first question is the most important), it might be a good idea to implement such a collection container `Items`.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it would be more appropriate to use a decorator here, if `Items` is to be used in several classes:

```
class Items {
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
}
```